# Многопоточность в Unity под Android

Tags: c#, многопоточность, unity3d

Во время игрового процесса, необходимо выполнять некоторую "длительную" работу. Игра подвисает на 2 секунды. Закинул выполнение этого алгоритма в отдельный поток и, как и ожидалось, все пошло плавно, но... только на ПК. При выполнении приложения на android, подвисание не исчезло.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я мог упустить? Может, есть какие то настройки компиляции, запрещающие многопоточность или что то вроде этого?

Comment: А на андроид устройстве ядер больше одного? А то многопоточность сойдет на нет

Comment: Meizu m3s.  8 ядер. Но не в этом суть. Даже при одном ядре, хоть и упадет производительность, но не должно быть зависаний.

Comment: На одном ядре будут зависания, т.к. забьется главный поток и приехали. Но не об этом. Предоставил бы пример реализации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема была не в самих потоках, а в том что они делали. Программа зависала от выделения/очистки большого куска памяти, который нужен был для второго потока. После некоторой оптимизации, проблема почти полностью ушла.

Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.

И да, в любых непонятных ситуациях  используйте profiler. Он покажет где, когда и, во многих случаях, почему происходит падение производительности.

Comment: Вашае заключительная  фраза звучит как: кто пытался, но не смог.

Answer (score 1):

В Unity для этого используются корутины.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: Не думаю что в данном случае мне подойдет корутина... Хотелось бы, все таки, разобраться с многопоточностью

Comment: Корутины используются только для временных событий, что бы не использовать `Update` который 99.9% времени в холостую долбит `if`. И она в мейн треде.